# How to remove whitespace at the very top in C

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Prototypes.
void print_hashes(int n);
void print_spaces(int n);

//Main function.
int main(void)
{
    //Recieves,checks and saves user input. Prompts to enter information again if invalid.
    int height = -1;
    while (height < 1 || height > 8)
    {
        height = get_int("Height: ");
    }

    //Outputs graphic to the screen with the use of logic with functions.
    for (int h = 0; h <= height; h++)
    {
        print_spaces(height - h);
        print_hashes(h);
        printf("  ");
        print_hashes(h);
        printf("\n");
    }
}


//Function for printing hashes to the screen.
void print_hashes(int n)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
}

//Function for printing spaces to the screen so the hashes will be in the right spot.
void print_spaces(int n)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Height: 8
          
       #  #
      ##  ##
     ###  ###
    ####  ####
   #####  #####
  ######  ######
 #######  #######
########  ########
```

You see at the top, right below height there is a space between the pyramid graphics and height: 8 I don't want that. Also I'm a mega C beginner no complex libraries and topics please just vanilla basic syntax.

So far I've tried

```
if (h > 0)
        {
        printf("\n");
        }
```

in the main for loop like this

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Prototypes.
void print_hashes(int n);
void print_spaces(int n);

//Main function.
int main(void)
{
    //Recieves,checks and saves user input. Prompts to enter information again if invalid.
    int height = -1;
    while (height < 1 || height > 8)
    {
        height = get_int("Height: ");
    }

    //Outputs graphic to the screen with the use of logic with functions.
    for (int h = 0; h <= height; h++)
    {
        print_spaces(height - h);
        print_hashes(h);
        printf("  ");
        print_hashes(h);
        if (h > 0)
        {
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
}


//Function for printing hashes to the screen.
void print_hashes(int n)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
}

//Function for printing spaces to the screen so the hashes will be in the right spot.
void print_spaces(int n)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
}
```

but get an output like this:

```
Height: 8
                 #  #
      ##  ##
     ###  ###
    ####  ####
   #####  #####
  ######  ######
 #######  #######
########  ########
```

**I want to know what I am getting wrong and how to fix it so that there is no space at the top.** Remember no advanced libraries or topics I just started this is my first problem set.

Comment: Do you know how to use a IDE along with a debugger?

Comment: Try the answer by @Unn  at https://onlinegdb.com/E_SfTICN5

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want the line containing 0 hashes, don't include it in your loop:

```
for (int h = 1; h <= height; h++)
```

Starting the loop at 1 drops the empty line from the loop.

Answer (score 2):

change the value of `h` from `0` to `1` in the `for loop`. It will work.

**Full Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Prototypes.
void print_hashes(int n);
void print_spaces(int n);

//Main function.
int main(void)
{
    //Recieves,checks and saves user input. Prompts to enter information again if invalid.
    int height = -1;
    while (height < 1 || height > 8)
    {   
        printf("Previous Height was: %d\n", height);
        scanf("%d", &height);
        printf("New Height is: %d\n", height);
    }

    //Outputs graphic to the screen with the use of logic with functions.
    for (int h = 1; h <= height; h++)
    {   
          print_spaces(height - h);
          print_hashes(h);
          printf("  ");
          print_hashes(h);
          printf("\n");
    }
}


//Function for printing hashes to the screen.
void print_hashes(int n)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
}

//Function for printing spaces to the screen so the hashes will be in the right spot.
void print_spaces(int n)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }
}
```

in This `for loop`

```
for (int h = 1; h <= height; h++)
    {   
          print_spaces(height - h);
          print_hashes(h);
          printf("  ");
          print_hashes(h);
          printf("\n");
    }
```

I Just changed the value of `h` from `0` to `1`

**My Output:**

```
Please enter new Height in the range between 1 to 8 including 1 and 8.                                                                                                                                                     
9                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Please enter new Height in the range between 1 to 8 including 1 and 8.                                                                                                                                                     
8                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
New Height is: 8 
       #  #                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      ##  ##                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     ###  ###                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    ####  ####                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   #####  #####                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  ######  ######                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 #######  ####### 
########  ########
```